# Use docker-compose exec instead of run if container already exists

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have a few invoke tasks written in Python (http://www.pyinvoke.org/) that are involving `docker-compose run --rm <service_name> <command>` commands to execute some stuff inside the container. However - I'd like to automatically execute `docker-compose exec <service_name> <command>` command if my service is already "up".

Is there any easy way to check if service is already running, and based on that - use `exec` instead of `run --rm`? Maybe there's some already existing `docker-compose` command I'm missing?

Example task:

```py
@task
def migrate(c):
    c.run("docker-compose run --rm web ./manage.py makemigrations")
    c.run("docker-compose run --rm web ./manage.py migrate")
```

Comment: It should be safe to always use `docker-compose run`.

Comment: even if it is, I don't see the point of creating new containers when I can just use `exec` on the running one. and I don't want to only use `exec` as sometimes I won't have running services

Comment: I stumbled upon this question because I want the same thing. Using `exec` is faster than `run` because run has to start up the container, which can take a second or two.